# Notice: Undefined index: username

Tags: php, sql, undefined, isset, undefined-index

I keep getting "Notice: Undefined index: username" when running this code.

> Notice: Undefined index: username in /public_html/handler.php on line
>   7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in /public_html/handler.php on line
>   8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: hwid in /public_html/handler.php on line 9

```
<?php

include('db.php');

$action = $_GET['action'];

$username = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$password = $con->real_escape_string(md5(md5(md5($_GET['password']))));
$hwid = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['hwid']);
$invite_code = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['invite_code']);

$logged = false;

if(!$action)
{
    echo "Error";
}
else
{   
if($action == "register_admin_xd")
{
    if($query = $con->query("INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES 
('$username','$password')"))
    {
        echo "1";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "0";
    }
}
```

here is the db.php

```
$host = "dbhostname";
$user = "dbusername";
$pass = "dbpassword";
$data = "database";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $data);

if($con->connect_errno)
{
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $con->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: Is the url passing values for those varaibles??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET); ` at very first line of script and share the result printed on screen

Comment: @ParitoshMahale i get Array
(
    [action] => login3
    [invite_code] => 1
)

Comment: @jophab Im using this php to pull from my database

Comment: it is not a good idea of sending password in url you should use $_POST method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update Code

**First check `$_GET` is [!empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function in php**

```
$username = !empty($_GET['username']) ? $con->real_escape_string($_GET['username']) : '';
$password = !empty($_GET['password']) ? $con->real_escape_string(md5(md5(md5($_GET['password'])))) : '';
$hwid = !empty($_GET['hwid']) ? $con->real_escape_string($_GET['hwid']) : '';
$invite_code = !empty($_GET['invite_code']) ? $con->real_escape_string($_GET['invite_code']) : '';
```

Answer (score -1):

you are not sending username,password and hwid in url thats why it showing error only for thos not for action and invite_code.
May be you are creating wrong url or you have empty value for username,password and hwid in url

Comment: I think because Aman gave a more direct answer, I can't downvote so it was the community.

Comment: i am not sure but if you see in comment $_GET contains Array ( [action] => login3 [invite_code] => 1 ) if he is creating wrong( without username and password value) url then system always get  empty values. he need to thing about that